# How can I include third-party javascript to run before my GWTTestCase?

Tags: gwt

I'm writing some end-to-end integration tests for a GWT library that's a thin wrapper over an existing Javascript library. I'd like to write my integration tests with the GWTTestCase infrastructure. When I go to run a unit test, though, it just pulls up my test code in some "junit-standards.html" file, and then promptly fails because it was expecting a global object to be attached to the window from the library I'm wrapping.

Is there a way to configure a GWTTestCase such that it includes third-party javascript before running the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ScriptInjector` helper to load the external javascript, and use a callback to continue with your test.

```java
ScriptInjector
  .fromUrl("http://my_3party_js")
  .setCallback(
    new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
      public void onFailure(Exception reason) {}
      public void onSuccess(Void result) {
       // test something
      }
    })
  .inject();
```

You can use as reference the `GWTTestCase`s which are in the test [ScriptInjectorTest.java](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/test/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjectorTest.java#L119) of the gwtproject.

Comment: One tip I found elsewhere is to add ".setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)" to the call in order to make the script available via $wnd.myfunc()